# Как рисовать пиксель-арт на языке Си

Tags: c

Узнал, что Pac-man написан на языке С, но игра 8-битная, а на языке можно делать игры только с разноцветными ASCII символами. Как был сделан этот пиксель-арт?

Comment: Какой конкретно Pac-man?

Comment: *на языке можно делать игры только с разноцветными ASCII символами* — с чего вы это взяли?...

Comment: классический Pac-man

Comment: Какой конкретно классический Pac-man?

Comment: Сделанный в 1980 году

Comment: А почему вы решили, что он написан на языке C?

Comment: Загуглил "Pac - Man на чём написан"

Comment: И почему вы решили, что гугл вам выдал не чушь?

Comment: А, нашел. Ну, это было под DOS и достаточно просто. Перепрограммируется знакогенератор, только и всего. Игрались в такие вещи. Русификаторы, например, так работали — но там один раз зашивается таблица; ну а тут вполне может просто обновляться по ходу дела.

Comment: @andreymal Да какая разница, на каком именно языке? :) Вопрос-то по сути не об этом.

Comment: @Harry во-первых, это было не под DOS, а на аркадном автомате. Во-вторых, в вопросе чётко обозначен язык C

Comment: Собственно вопрос: почему нет? Можно, и не только с разноцветными ASCII символами, но ещё и в 3D!)) Вот скрин с результатом моего эксперимента на фоне открытого исходника: https://i.postimg.cc/rst4bGfH/444.png

Answer (score 0):

Сам язык C, да и в принципе любой ЯП никогда не давал возможность рисовать графику. Объясню кратко это на примере того же пак мена:
Оригинальная игра изначально выходила на игровых автоматах. И игра имела возможность отрисовывать графику благодаря железу игрового автомата, а не наличия языка C, с тем же успехом могли использовать BASIC или Pascal. Я не знаю, как работало железо на том автомате, но могу сказать с уверенностью, что на языке программист си обращался к процессору ответственному за вывод изображения на дисплей в нужном виде. И там есть своя логика работы с банками памяти, ОЗУ, прерываниями и тд, которой Я не интересовался. А вот к примеру для NES(Денди) она абсолютно иная. Тоже самое для GameBoy, Sega и прочих консолей. Вот поэтому в те времена было мало мультиплатформенных игр. В основном портируют самые успешные проекты. Так что для разных устройств код приходилось писать с нуля, даже для одной и той же игры. Если интересуют тематика, как работали игровые консоли тех времён, можешь заценить ютуб канал кластера.

Если ты хочешь написать игру пакмен для твоего ПК(который скорее всего работает на винде) на языке С, то Я бы тебе порекомендовал использовать библиотеку SFML. Это оболочка для OpenGL. Думаю для новичка освоить сразу OpenGL будет сложно, да и не стоит, ведь эту библиотеку активно замещает Vulcan. А SFML хороший способ, чтобы понять нравиться тебе это или нет.

P.S. Прошу всех кто разбирается больше меня подправить или дополнить мой ответ.

Comment: SFML для плюсов, а для голых С есть SDL2 (и из плюсов им тоже вполне можно пользоваться).